# Matrix representation for panel data

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, kronecker-product

Consider the following panel data matrix

individuals $n = 3$, time periods $t = 2$, and variables $p=2$. The design matrix
$\mathbf{X} = \big(\mathbf{x}_1 \,\, \mathbf{x}_2 \big) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1\\-1&8 \\ 4&6\\3&-3 \\ 9&5\\11&7
\end{pmatrix}_{nt \times p}$

I want to diagonalize each column w.r.t. each individual and then put them next to each other as follows:

$\mathbf{Z} =
\begin{pmatrix}
2&0&0&1&0&0\\-1&0&0&8&0&0 \\ 0&4&0&0&6&0\\0&3&0&0&-3&0 \\ 0&0&9&0&0&5\\0&0&11&0&0&7
\end{pmatrix}_{nt\times np}
$

To represent this in matrix multiplication, I did the following

- define a selection matrix $\mathbf{D}_{nt \times n} = \boldsymbol{I}_{n\times n} \otimes \mathbf{1}_{t\times 1}$
- $\mathbf{Z} = \Big[\big(\mathbf{1}_{n\times 1}^{\tau} \otimes \mathbf{x}_1\big) \odot \mathbf{D}, \big(\mathbf{1}_{n\times 1}^{\tau} \otimes \mathbf{x}_2\big) \odot \mathbf{D}  \Big]$ where $\otimes$ and $\odot$ are the kronecker and the element-wise products, respectively.

This absolutely does what I am looking for, yet I am looking forward to a much easier matrix representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your idea to its logical conclusion by defining the following *zero-one matrices*
$$\eqalign{
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\I{{I}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\R#1{\in{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
P &= \I_p\otimes\o_n^T \\
S &= \o_p^T\otimes\I_n\otimes\o_t \\
}$$
Then you can convert the whole $X$ matrix in one step
$$\eqalign{
Z &= \LR{XP}\odot S \\
}$$
To be clear, $\,\o_p\R{p}$ is a column vector of ones, and $I_n\R{n\times n}$ is the identity matrix.